# Determinant of matrix representation of a linear operator associated with cyclotomic extension

Tags: determinant, galois-extensions

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $\zeta_{p}$ be the pth roots of unity and le $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p})/\mathbb{Q}$ be a Galois extension and $G=Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p})/\mathbb{Q})$ be its Galois group we know that $|G|=\phi(p)=p-1 $
And let $S=\{1,\zeta,\zeta^{2},.....,\zeta^{p-2}\}$ be a basis of the Galois extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p})/\mathbb{Q}$ and let $m_{\alpha}(x)=\alpha x $ be a linear operator .and $[m_{\alpha}]$ be its matrix representation

Edit : $\alpha=1+a_{1}\zeta$

My question whether any formula for $det([m_{\alpha}])$ or at least an approximation of determinant matrix of cyclotomic extension ?

Comment: You never define $\alpha$. Should that be $m_{\zeta}$ instead?

Comment: Also, I suppose that you are asking about $\det[m_{\alpha}]$ as opposed to $\det[m_{\alpha}x]$.

Comment: Surely that would be the norm of $\alpha$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1:** What is the minimal polynomial of $m_{\alpha}$? How does the minimal polynomial of a linear operator relate to its characteristic polynomial?

---

**Hint 2:** Let $p$ denote the polynomial
$$
p(x) = 1+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^{2}+.....+a_{p-2}x^{p-2}.
$$

The "spectral mapping theorem" tells us that for each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $m_{\zeta}$, $p(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $p(m_{\zeta}) = m_{p(\zeta)} = m_\alpha$.

*Edit:* With your latest change: suppose $a_1 \neq 0$. We have $\alpha = 1 + a_1 \zeta = a_1(\zeta + a_1^{-1})$. The determinant of $m_\alpha$ is simply given by
$$
\det(m_{\alpha}) = \det(a_1(m_{\zeta} - a_1^{-1})) = a_1^{p-2} \det(m_{\xi} - a_1^{-1}) = a_1^{p-2}\chi_{\zeta}(a_1^{-1}).
$$

Comment: $\pi_{\alpha}(x)=\chi_{\alpha}(x)$ if the minimal polynomial $\pi _{\alpha}(x)$ split completely over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ and $\chi_{\alpha}$ is the characterstic polynomial of [m_{\alpha}]

Comment: actually I can't write the general form of the matrix $[m_{\alpha}] $ if you can write it here

Comment: @Abdo if we know the characteristic polynomial, then $\det(m_{\alpha}) = \chi_{\alpha}(0)$

Comment: @Abdo But also, now that I understand what $\alpha$ is supposed to be, things change quite a bit

Comment: @Abdo see my latest edit

Comment: Now I change it can do something now

Comment: @Abdo Again, see my latest edit

Comment: can you tell me what is the spectral mapping theorem says .or give me a reference

Comment: @Abdo For a linear map $T$: if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, then $p(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $p(T)$.